# How do I show a HTML editor in an ASP.NET MVC 4 page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been working on an MVC app. Currently I use `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TextField)` to display a textbox.

Now I want to use a WYSIWYG HTML Editor instead but don't know how to incorporate this into the Razor View. I already have the field set as to allow html in my model.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Good Question even i am interested to know this

Comment: Read about "editor templates" and choose a WYSIWYG editor like TinyMCE, KendoUI edtor, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php) then you can do something like this:

**The Model**

```
public class EditorModel
{  
    [UIHint("tinymce_full"), AllowHtml]
    public string TextField { get; set; }
}
```

**The Template** under Shared -> EditorTemplates

```
@*
Don't forget to reference the JQuery Library here, inside your view or layout.
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-x.x.x.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
*@

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    (function () {

        $(function () {

            $('#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty)').tinymce({

                // Location of TinyMCE script
                script_url: '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/tiny_mce.js")',
                theme: "advanced",

                height: "500",
                width: "500",
                verify_html: false,
                plugins: "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist", //,autosave

                // Theme options
                theme_advanced_buttons1: "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
                theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
                theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
                theme_advanced_buttons4: "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft,codehighlighting,netadvimage",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
                theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
                theme_advanced_resizing: false,

                // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
                //            content_css : "@Url.Content("~/Content/style.css")",
                convert_urls: false,

                // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
                template_external_list_url: "lists/template_list.js",
                external_link_list_url: "lists/link_list.js",
                external_image_list_url: "lists/image_list.js",
                media_external_list_url: "lists/media_list.js",

                valid_elements: "@@[span]"
            });

        });

    })();

</script>

@Html.TextArea(string.Empty, /* Name suffix */
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue /* Initial value */
)
```

**View Implementation**

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.TextField)
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking that I call the view in the editor templates folder tinymce_full.cshtml?

It seems to be calling it but still just rendering the textarea (using the code provided above) like so:

`<textarea Length="2226" cols="20" data-val="true" data-val-required="The nContent field is required." id="nContent" name="nContent" rows="2">`

Comment: The first parameter to `UIHint` is `The user control (field template) to use to display the data field.`. So yes you are right. Did you ensure you have all required files by tinymce and they are on the right paths?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be rendering a tinymce editor. 

My model has:'
        [Required]
        [UIHint("tinymce_full"), AllowHtml]
        public string Content { get; set; }
'

My view has: `<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nContent)`

And the tinymce editorview is a c&p from above

Comment: I downloaded the TinyMCE 3.5.8 jQuery package. Do I just need this or just the TinyMCE 3.5.8 download?

Comment: Ok, got past that but now get:

0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'tinymce'

Comment: Cracked it now. Was an issue with my link to JQuery. Thanks